# Backup from HD Image (Mac)

Tags: mac, backup, disk-utility

I am trying to recover a system from a `dmg`. I copied the `dmg` onto my `Documents` folder and select the correct drive as shown:

[image: location of image]
I did this by

```
1. dragged and dropped `MacIntosh HD` onto the destination field
2. clicked on the source input field
3. clicked on the `Linc Standard Image.dmg`
```

I always get this error and can't get over it. I've tried creating a new image several times but always getting the same error.
[image: this is the error]

Comment: Are you trying to read the dmg from the same drive you're about to wipe & replace with the dmg?

Comment: yes. Should I create a separate partition, copy the drive, and delete the old one?

Comment: The trick, really, is to get the .dmg off the drive you're working onto - either by partitioning & having it on the partition you're not going to overwrite, or by copying it to another drive altogether [possibly safer, long-term] As you've discovered, the system won't let you wipe & install the volume the .dmg is on, or it wouldn't be there to copy from... ;-)

Comment: I actually did put the `dmg` onto an external drive put the source from there, but I am getting the same error as well.

Comment: 1) Did you drag the new .dmg to Disk Utility, otherwise it will keep trying to use the old one. 2) Have you tried mounting the .dmg on the desktop, to test it's OK?

Comment: 1) yes 2) I could not mount the DMG on the desktop...Does this mean it's a bad disk image? I repeated imaging the original drive several times though...

Comment: I'd be tempted to try using Carbon Copy Cloner [it has a free 30-day trial] - I'm not sure whether a standard .dmg can accurately copy a boot drive.

Comment: Tetsujin, CCC worked great for me!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you